# Exceptions handler is not working in Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-webflux

Hi I am new using web flux (Mono and Flux) and I am trying to create a controller that consume a service using webflux to bring a list in Cassandra, but I would like to throw a personalized exception when the list is null or empty, I had be trying to create a GlobalExceptionHandler and my personalized exception and when the list is not null the response is ok, but when the list is null and when I use postman, it shows me the status ok but the body not, could you help me resolving this, please. this is my code.

this is the GlobalExceptionHandler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<UseCaseListResponse> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException exception, WebRequest request){
    UseCaseListResponse useCaseListResponse = new UseCaseListResponse(MessageInformation.ERROR.getMessage(),
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
            exception.getMessage(), null);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(useCaseListResponse);
}
}
```

This is my personalized exception

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
private String resourceName;
private String fieldName;
private String fieldValue;

public ResourceNotFoundException(String resourceName, String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
    super(String.format("%s not was found with: %s = %s ", resourceName, fieldName, fieldValue));
    this.resourceName = resourceName;
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
}

public ResourceNotFoundException(String resourceName) {
    super(String.format("%s not was found", resourceName));
    this.resourceName = resourceName;

}}
```

Service Method

```
@Override
public Mono<UseCaseListResponse> listAllQuotes() {
    return quoteRepository
                    .findAll()
                    .collectList()
                    .flatMap(entities -> {
                        if(entities == null || entities.isEmpty()){
                            return Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Quotes"));

                        }else{
                            return Mono.just(entities);
                        }
                    })
                    .map(entities -> new UseCaseListResponse(
                            MessageInformation.SUCCESS.getMessage(),
                            HttpStatus.OK.value(),
                            HttpStatus.OK.getReasonPhrase(),
                            QuoteOutMapper.entityListToDtoList(entities)))
                    .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error listing entities: " + error.getMessage()));

}
```

This is the controller

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<UseCaseListResponse> example(){
    return quoteAdapter.listAllQuotes()
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .onErrorResume(ResourceNotFoundException.class,
                    ex -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()))
            .onErrorResume(Throwable.class,
                    ex -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build()))
            .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error listing entities: " + error.getMessage())).block();
}
```